# How to get Google analytics client id for mobile app (not mobile websites)

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

In website (desktop or mobile), GA generates `client_id` and stores in `_ga` cookie. This I can easily retrieve using `gtag`.

For mobile app, do we have to generate & set client_id ourselves ? Because I cannot find related documentation for this.
If we have to generate ourselves, can we use any uuid or Firebase `app_instance_id` as ga client id.

Comment: maybe this will help you:
https://www.tatvic.com/blog/implement-google-analytics-client-id-android-marketing/

Comment: If I generate myself and use it as client id , will it work still ? @EvyatarCohen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client id` in gtag is equivalent to `app instance id` in firebase
`tracking id` in gtag is equivalent to `app id` (or `project id`, idk) in firebase

So answer is we can use `app instance id` of firebase as equivalent of client id.

Similarity between two:

- client id indicates a particular install (not technically) of a website. It remains unchanged for 2 years unless that website is hard-refreshed
- app instance id also indicates a particular install of an app on phone and remains same till app in uninstalled